# How can i assign overlayItems to list of GeoPoints

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i have written the following codings:

```
locations.add(new GeoPoint((int)(3.1667652777 * 1E6),(int)(101.70002277 * 1E6)));
locations.add(new GeoPoint((int)(3.16676 * 1E6),(int)(101.6836 * 1E6)));
```

Note: i am using `ArrayList` for the above.
How do i add overlay item for the above locations? I saw the android development website mentioning:

```
GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(35410000, 139460000);
OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Sekai, konichiwa!", "I'm in Japan!");
```

Do need to do something similar as shared by the website or can i just stick with my coding?

Answer (score 0):

**ItemizedOverlayClass**

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> myOverlays ;

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        myOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        populate();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay){
        myOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return myOverlays.get(i);
    }

    // Removes overlay item i
    public void removeItem(int i){
        myOverlays.remove(i);
        populate();
    }

    // Returns present number of items in list
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return myOverlays.size();
    }


    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
        myOverlays.add(overlayItem);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ActivityClass**

```
private MyItemizedOverlay nearPicOverlay;    
nearPicOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(atmPic);
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    nearatms[i] = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(latitude) * 1E6),(int)((longitude) * 1E6),"", null);
                    nearPicOverlay.addOverlay(nearatms[i]);
                }
```

Please check the brackets because i don't have eclipse and just typed directly. Hope this will help....